# Please help me recover from this. I can't access my files nor Internet connection

Tags: unity, home-directory

I restarted my pc after installing some applications from the terminal, and found my desktop this way i can't see home folder, desktop files and there is no network access and i can shutdown without the terminal. Please help me recover from this.

Comment: Please show the image you speak of, and what  app did you install?

Comment: Now that it booted up successfully, no need to panic. Try shortcuts, for terminal `ctrl-alt-t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, please try and start a TTY session by clicking the buttons crtl + alt + f3 concurrently. After the console pops up, please login in via entering your username and password. Then, depending on whether you use `gdm` or `lightdm`, restart the display manager by running `sudo service lightdm restart` or `sudo service gdm restart`... After running either command the display manager will restart and you should then be able to login.